# How to Clone Existing Items Into Circular Slider On Beginning and End

Tags: javascript, jquery, jcarousel

Can you please take a look at  [<kbd>This Demo</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/Ls0ex5t0/)   let me know how I can clone items into the  ul  to make a  Circular Slider  list. as you can see I have this list as following code but I need to clone  first item (left slide) or last item (right slide) at   beginning  and end of the list.

```
var item = $(".thumbnail").width();
var paddT = $(".thumbnail").css('margin-left');
item = item + 20;
$(".leftslide").on("click", function () {
    $(".list-inline").animate({
        left: '-=' + item + 'px'
    }, 300);
});
$(".rightslide").on("click", function () {
    $(".list-inline").animate({
        left: '+=' + item + 'px'
    }, 300);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You need to clone first item when you got empty place clicking on ">"? Do you need to clone multiple times (every time you navigate to empty place, having multiple cloned elements)? Do you need to delete cloned elements when you navigate back to normal ones?

Comment: Hi Regent and thanks for reply.Yes I think I need multiple clones on both ">" and "<" empty spcases

Comment: What about removing them when they are not necessary more (when you moved away from them)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First/last `li` is cloned and prepends/appends to `.list-inline` when necessary after `.list-inline` animation:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls0ex5t0/5/).

```
var item = $(".thumbnail").width();
var paddT = $(".thumbnail").css('margin-left');
item = item + 20;

var list = $(".list-inline");

$(".leftslide").on("click", function()
{
    list.animate
    (
        {
            left: '-=' + item + 'px'
        },
        300, 
        function()
        {
            if (parseInt(list.css("left")) >= -$(".list-inline li").length * item)
            {
                list.find("li:last").clone().appendTo(list);
            }
        }
    );
});

$(".rightslide").on("click", function()
{
    $(".list-inline").animate
    (
        {
            left: '+=' + item + 'px'
        },
        300,
        function()
        {
            if (parseInt(list.css("left")) >= item)
            {
                list.find("li:first").clone().prependTo(list);
                list.css("left", '-=' + item + 'px');
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: Hi Regent and thanks for you great work but there is only one minor issue here! as you can see the slide is perfectly when you slide "<" but in ">" looks like items are dropping into the list! is there any way to do the same thing to have a smooth clone here too? can we clone to left on load and have the items ready just like the opposite slide direction?

Comment: @user3649067 take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls0ex5t0/6/). I modified `$(".rightslide")` click handler and added `.list-inline { left: 0; }` in CSS.

Comment: Thanks Regent this is working now But I just noticed another issue Here : [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls0ex5t0/8/) . if you slide to left or right Only the last item added to the end and First item to left! can you please try this?

Comment: @user3649067 yes, this is what your question is about: cloning first element clicking on ">" and cloning last element clicking on "<": _"I need to clone first item (left slide) or last item (right slide) at beginning and end of the list"_.

Comment: Yeah I realy sorry about that it is my bad! what I was looking for was adding the whole slider from beginning to the end and from end to beginning! still confusing ! ha?! something like circling 1-2-3-4-5 in both side

Comment: Great!  this is exactly what was I was looking for and again sorry about confusion!

Answer (score 0):

> **JQuery**

```
var count=$(".thumbnail").length;
var item = $(".thumbnail").width();
var paddT = $(".thumbnail").css('margin-left');
item = item + 20;
$(".leftslide").on("click", function () {
    $(".list-inline").animate({
        left: '-=' + item + 'px'
    }, 300,function(){
        var lastTmb=$(".thumbnail:last");        
        if(lastTmb.offset().left<0)
        {
            //for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
                 //$(".thumbnail:first").parent().insertAfter(lastTmb.parent());
            //}
            $(".list-inline").animate({
               left: '+=' + item*count + 'px'
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});
$(".rightslide").on("click", function () {
    $(".list-inline").animate({
        left: '+=' + item + 'px'
    }, 300,function(){
        var firstTmb=$(".thumbnail:first");        
        if(firstTmb.offset().left>0)
        {
            //for (i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
                 //$(".thumbnail:last").parent().insertAfter(firstTmb.parent());
            //}
            $(".list-inline").animate({
               left: '-=' + item*count + 'px'
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/hamix/fsz632zj/)